# How to import .js file to .ts in ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript

I have create a .js file inside my /www/js/N.js after that I include in the index.html like src="assests/js/getImage.js"> and the script is before the build/polyfills.js

After that, what should I do to get my .js file working ??

here is my source code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/getImage.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

May I know is there any import js to ts tutorial available ?? 
I found a lot on youtube but none of them meet my requirement. !! 
Thanks in advance, please help me. Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example `import './a';`

Comment: ya..I have tried that too. But that are not working, instead I switch from import './a'; to declare var function = myFunction; the error gone, but just that the script is not running..no idea why.

Comment: declare is completely unrelated.

Comment: Okay, so may I have some tutorial about it ?? Do you have it ??